# jdk and gradle problems

Tags: java, gradle

I have a family protocol problem
It says your jDk uses different locations, is not detected, and gives an error
I installed jDK and gave it the route, but it still gives the same error. Can you help me?

It gives such an error

```
AM  Gradle sync failed: Protocol family unavailable
                Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (10 s 120 ms)

3:20 AM Android Studio is using the following JDK location when running Gradle:
                C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181
                Using different JDK locations on different processes might cause Gradle to
                spawn multiple daemons, for example, by executing Gradle tasks from a terminal
                while using Android Studio.
                More info...
                Select a JDK from the File System
                Do not show this warning again
```